# Objective-C: NSStatusBar right and left click

Tags: objective-c, nsstatusitem

how to detect left or right click on statusbar icon, and than make some action, depending on which mouse button (trackpad) was clicked?

I use:

```
  _statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];
  [_statusItem setMenu:menu];
  [_statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
```

To generate statusBar icon

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To detect the mouse buttons that are currently pressed, you can use `[NSEvent pressedMouseButtons]`.

To detect the status bar icon being clicked, you can detect the menu appearing. Just before a menu opens, it sends a menuWillOpen: message to its delegate (if it has one). So implement something like this:

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu
{
  NSLog(@"%d",[NSEvent pressedMouseButtons]);
}
```

You will also need to set the delegate for the menu, for example by

```
[menu setDelegate:self];
```